# How to import a pre-existing sqlite file into core data iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

Ive created a new core data project and set up my core data model. I then ran it in the simulator and then saved the context. I then used Core Data Editor 5 to open up and view my data base. I added and edited new entitles, saved the file, then i went into the simulator to check out if it worked and everything was added and looked fine. I now want to add this data base to my project bundle and have the app load this bata base as its default core data data base. With the new wal system I cant seem to get it to work. I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix it. Ive heard that you have to add all 3 files (.sqlite,wal,shm) but I dont know where exactly to save it or through what process to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Add all three to your iOS application as resources. Then

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfilename" ofType:@"myfileextension"]];
```

and pass that to your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` in the call to `-addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:...`.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfilename" ofType:@"myfileextension"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                   configuration:nil
                                                             URL:storeURL
                                                         options:@{NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption : @YES,
                                                                   NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{ @"journal_mode" : @"WAL"}}
                                                           error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        */

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Having given you that snippet, though, that's not the way I do it, and I don't know that it will work. Instead, if I'm creating a static datastore to use as readonly data, I'll use the old `DELETE` journal mode when I create the datastore (in another tool or program) and when I read it in my actual iOS app. That means changing the `options:` parameter (on both the creation code and the read code).

```
              options:@{NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption : @YES,
                        NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{ @"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"}}
```

http://www.sqlite.org/draft/wal.html states "It is not possible to open read-only WAL databases." with further discussion at http://www.sqlite.org/draft/wal.html#readonly.